# Get users with username query issue

Tags: ios, backendless

I have a search bar and want to have a query that will get the users which first letters match search bar text. Now I have a query

> "username LIKE '%@'"

which only gets users that username = "Search bar text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
...username LIKE '%%%@%%'....
```

Comment: Sorry can you write it in objc 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username LIKE '%@&'", username]
I put It like this but it doesn't works

Comment: Hey Sorry Made A Typo
Use `%` instead of `&`

Comment: like this 
"username LIKE '$%@$'"

Comment: Like this: "username LIKE '%@%'", in your case

Comment: still same result ''%@' puts my property in string its equals to variable,and abut second % compiler says that not current format

Comment: here is it "username LIKE '%%%@%%'"

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that in iOS you have to handle it like that